# Insert datatable in to sql table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datatable named `dt2`. And it contains some data. I want to add these data to my table named `invitationdata`.

How can I write the code? Can any one help?

Comment: Nobody mentioned it but this is a very low quality question. First of all, what have you tried so far? Show your effort first.. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 string sql = "";
 for (int i = 0; i < dt2.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
    sql = sql + "insert into InvitationData (Col1, Col2, ColN) values('"
          + dt2.Rows[i]["columnname"].ToString().Trim() + "','"
          + dt2.Rows[i]["columnname"].ToString().Trim() + "','" 
          + dt2.Rows[i]["columnname"].ToString().Trim() + "')";
 }
```

Comment: dt.Rows[i]["columnname"]  ..What you mean by columnname ???

Comment: Your datatable column names.

Comment: SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(GlobalSettings.DbDSN, CommandType.Text,
                    "INSERT INTO xmasinvitation(Name,Email)VALUES(" + dt2.Rows[j]["Name"].ToString().Trim()+ "," + dt2.Rows[j]["email"].ToString().Trim() + ") ");


I coded like above .but catch the exception ... (Invalid column name 'arun'.

The multi-part identifier "am@phases.dk" could not be bound.)

Comment: Check the updated answer. Include ' in the values.

Answer (score 39):

```
public bool BulkInsertDataTable(string tableName, DataTable dataTable)
{
    bool isSuccuss;
    try
    {
        SqlConnection SqlConnectionObj = GetSQLConnection();
        SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(SqlConnectionObj, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock | SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers | SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction, null);
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
        isSuccuss = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        isSuccuss = false;
    }
    return isSuccuss;
}
```

Comment: +1 for syntax of sql bulk copy

Comment: this is the best answer. +1 for this.

Comment: Is this missing some connection open & close commands?

Comment: @PhillHealey: No, It is a generic method which you can call in your required place by passing param as your table name and dataTable, check the place in which you are calling this method, connection open and close is required or not

Answer (score 2):

If your datatable and your table structure is same , then you can use [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) which would be a faster option if the datatable contains large number of rows.

**SqlBulkCopy**

> Lets you efficiently bulk load a SQL Server table with data from
>   another source.

Comment: please note....even if the structure is NOT same you can still map columns.

Answer (score 1):

use `INSERT INTO...SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO InvitationData (Col1, Col2, ColN)
SELECT Col1, Col2, ColN
FROM   DT2
```

What it does is it selects all records (*or specified record*) and inserts it on the other table.

Comment: The first `table` is not a `database table`. It is a C# `datatable` which is a collection of `row` and `columns`